# why x works but is undeclared? c++

Tags: c++

One of the example problems i am basing a program off of for secant root finding uses x, but doesn't declare it, but runs successfully. Meanwhile when i use the nearly the same setup i get an error saying x is undeclared. Why does it work in the example program and not mine?

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
// Declaration of functions used
void secant(double, double, double, double,
               double, double, double&, int& );
double fx(double, double, double, double, double);
const double tol=0.0001;    // Tolerance for convergence
const int max_iter=50;      // Maximum iterations allowed
// main program
int main()
{
    int iteration;          // Number of iterations
    double a, b, c, d;      // Constants in f(x)
    double x0, x1;          // Starting values for x
    double root;           // Root found by secant method
    cout<<"Enter a, b, c, and d"<<endl<<"separated by a space ";
    cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
    cout<<"\nEnter two initial values for x,\nseparated by a space: ";
    cin>>x0>>x1;
    secant(a, b, c, d, x0, x1, root, iteration);// Call "secant"
// Output
    cout<<"\nThe root is = "<<root<<endl;
    cout<<"The number of iterations was = "<<iteration<<endl;
    cout<<"The value of f(x) at the root = "<<fx(a,b,c,d,root)<<endl<<endl;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
// Definition of function "secant"
// Receives a, b, c, d and x0 values from main program
// Returns root and the iterations required
void secant(double a,double b, double c, double d, 
        double x0, double x1, double& root, int& iteration)
{
    double xnminus1, xnplus1, xn; // Local variables
    iteration=0;                  // Initialize iterations
    xnminus1=x0;
    xn=x1;
    do
    {
       ++iteration;
       xnplus1 = xn - fx(a,b,c,d,xn)*(xn-xnminus1)/
                                  (fx(a,b,c,d,xn)-fx(a,b,c,d,xnminus1));
       cout<<"x"<<iteration+1<<" = "<<xnplus1<<endl;
       xnminus1 = xn;
       xn=xnplus1;
    }  
    while ((fabs(fx(a,b,c,d,xnplus1)) >= tol )&& (iteration < max_iter));
    root=xnplus1;  
}
// Defines "fx" -- calculates f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
double fx(double a, double b, double c, double d, double x)
{
    return a*pow(x,3)+b*pow(x,2)+c*x+d;
}
```

here is my program which i used the same structure but it is saying x is undeclared?

```
 using namespace std;
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cmath>
    #include<iomanip>
    #include<fstream>
    // Declaration of functions used
    void secant(double, double, double, double,
                   double, double, double, double, double&, int& );
    double fx( double, double, double, double, double, double, double);
    const double tol=0.0001;    // Tolerance for convergence
    const int max_iter=50;      // Maximum iterations allowed
    // main program
    int main()
    {
        int iteration;          // Number of iterations

        double kr, uc, q, b, radians;

        double x0, x1;          // Starting values for x
        double root;           // Root found by secant method
    const double PI = 4.0*atan(1.0);
    ifstream datain ("shuttle.txt");
    ofstream dataout ("results.txt");
    datain >> kr >> uc >> q >> b;
    int velocity = 16000;
    double angle =10;
    x0= 1000;
    x1 = 200;
    for (int velocity = 16000; velocity <= 17500; velocity += 500) {
        for (int angle = 10; angle <= 70; angle += 15) {
    radians= angle * PI/180  ;
                  cout << velocity << endl;
                  cout << radians << endl;
                  cout << angle << endl;
                  secant (radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, x0, x1, root, iteration);

    // Output
        cout<<"\nThe root is = "<<root<<endl;
        cout<<"The number of iterations was = "<<iteration<<endl;
        cout<<"The value of f(x) at the root = "<<fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, root)<<endl<<endl;
     system("pause");
     return 0;
    }
    // Definition of function "secant"
    // Receives a, b, c, d and x0 values from main program
    // Returns root and the iterations required
    void secant(double radians,double velocity, double kr, double uc, double q, double b, double x0, double x1, double& root, int& iteration);
    {
        double xnminus1, xnplus1, xn; // Local variables
        iteration=0;                  // Initialize iterations
        xnminus1=x0;
        xn=x1;
        do
        {
           ++iteration;
           xnplus1 = xn - fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xn)*(xn-xnminus1)/
                                      (fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xn)-fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xnminus1));
           cout<<"x"<<iteration+1<<" = "<<xnplus1<<endl;
           xnminus1 = xn;
           xn=xnplus1;
        }  
        while ((fabs(fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xnplus1)) >= tol )&& (iteration < max_iter));
        root=xnplus1;  
    }
    // Defines "fx" -- calculates f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
    double fx(double radians,double velocity, double kr, double uc, double q, double b, double x);
    {
         return kr * pow(x,4.0) + uc * x - q - pow(velocity/b, 2.0) * sin(radians);

    }}
    }
```

Comment: So is this the code that compiles and works? The only x I see is the parameter in function fx()....

Comment: x is declared in fx. Where is it throwing an error (or not)?

Comment: Could you show the case where it does work?

Comment: this is the case that it does work, put it through a complier to test, do you want me to upload my program that is throwing off errors?

Comment: @Brian: that would help, so we could compare the two versions.

Comment: I added it underneath the one that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double fx(double radians,double velocity, double kr, double uc, double q, double b, double x);
```

you have an extra semicolon ";" at the end of the line. :)

Should be

```
double fx(double radians,double velocity, double kr, double uc, double q, double b, double x)
```

You also have the same error when defining the secant function. When you define a function you don't put a semicolon at the end.

Final code should look something like this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
// Declaration of functions used
void secant(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double&, int& );
double fx( double, double, double, double, double, double, double);
const double tol=0.0001;    // Tolerance for convergence
const int max_iter=50;      // Maximum iterations allowed

using namespace std; // <- Goes after including the headers

// main program
int main()
{
        int iteration;          // Number of iterations

        double kr, uc, q, b, radians;

        double x0, x1;          // Starting values for x
        double root;           // Root found by secant method
        const double PI = 4.0*atan(1.0);
        ifstream datain ("shuttle.txt");
        ofstream dataout ("results.txt");
        datain >> kr >> uc >> q >> b;
        int velocity = 16000;
        double angle =10;
        x0= 1000;
        x1 = 200;
        for (int velocity = 16000; velocity <= 17500; velocity += 500)
        {
            for (int angle = 10; angle <= 70; angle += 15)
        {
            radians= angle * PI/180  ;
                    cout << velocity << endl;
                    cout << radians << endl;
                    cout << angle << endl;
                    secant (radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, x0, x1, root, iteration);
        }
    }

    // Output
        cout<<"\nThe root is = "<<root<<endl;
        cout<<"The number of iterations was = "<<iteration<<endl;
        cout<<"The value of f(x) at the root = "<<fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, root)<<endl<<endl;
        system("pause");
     return 0;
}


// Definition of function "secant"
// Receives a, b, c, d and x0 values from main program
// Returns root and the iterations required
void secant(double radians,double velocity, double kr, double uc, double q, double b, double x0, double x1, double& root, int& iteration)
{
        double xnminus1, xnplus1, xn; // Local variables
        iteration=0;                  // Initialize iterations
        xnminus1=x0;
        xn=x1;
        do
        {
           ++iteration;
           xnplus1 = xn - fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xn)*(xn-xnminus1)/
                                      (fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xn)-fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xnminus1));
           cout<<"x"<<iteration+1<<" = "<<xnplus1<<endl;
           xnminus1 = xn;
           xn=xnplus1;
        }  
        while ((fabs(fx(radians, velocity, kr, uc, q, b, xnplus1)) >= tol )&& (iteration < max_iter));
        root=xnplus1;  
}


// Defines "fx" -- calculates f(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d
double fx(double radians,double velocity, double kr, double uc, double q, double b, double x)
{
        return kr * pow(x,4.0) + uc * x - q - pow(velocity/b, 2.0) * sin(radians);

}
```

Comment: i added the ; because i received an error saying " expected ; before return" and "a function definition is not allowed here before return"  and that solved the error

Comment: @Brian That's because you are not closing the brackets "}" of your for loops properly and the compiler thinks that you are trying to define the function inside the loop.

Comment: how would i change it to close it properly?

Comment: @Brian I edited my answer to reflect that. I also suggest you place your brackets on separate lines. That way you can easily check which ones are still unclosed. Another good practice is to close the bracket right after you open it and then fill in your code. That way you won't miss closing any.

Comment: @Brian I just noticed that you have a lot of misplaced "}". I edited the code to make it compile

Comment: @Brian Cool :) Just remember though never add random stuff just to make the code work, understanding what was wrong in the first place is essential (and half the "fun")

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you mean the `x` variable in the function `fx`:

`x` is declared as a parameter, hence why it can be used without an explicit local variable declaration. what might be throwing you off is the forward declaration of `fx` hasn't got names for its args

Comment: why does it not work in my program? I followed the same layout?